# How to show notification dot (Oreo) on Android app launcher?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to show notification dot on Android app launcher, which available in Android Oreo APK. How to implement this?

I have tried [Shortcut Badger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) but not working.

[image: As shown in image]

Answer (score 2):

Refer this link: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges
set `notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true or false);`